# Python Printing Quotation Marks on Two Lines Instead of One

Tags: python

I am reading from an external text file, named 'greeting.txt' where the contents of the text file are simply:

```
HELLO
```

However, when I attempt to print the contents of the text file enclosed in quotes the terminal prints out:

```
"HELLO
"
```

I am using the following code:

```
for line in open('greeting.txt', "r"): print ('"%s"' % line)
```

I desire the string to be enclosed in quotes printed on the same line. 
I have never encountered this problem before despite using Python for similar purposes, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a end of line character in your text file after Hello. That end of line is also getting enclosed in the double quotes and causing the second quote to get printed on the second line. You should strip the end of line using rstrip()

```
for line in open('greeting.txt', "r"): print ('"%s"' % line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, what is written in your file is probably `Hello\n` and if you read the whole line you are then printing `"Hello\n"` which causes the newline to be in front of the second quote. Use the `strip()` method to get rid of any trailing whitespaces like so:

```
 for line in open('greeting.txt', "r"): print ('"%s"' % line.strip())
```

However I would suggest changing your code to:

```
with open('greeting.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f: print ('"%s"' % line.strip())
```

Since I personally do not like to have `open` without making sure, that the file is being closed as soon as I am done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the trailing whitespaces using the `rstrip()` function.

```
for line in open('greeting.txt', "r"): print ('"%s"' % line.rstrip())
```